# Python destructors in new and old style classes

Tags: python, destructor

I'm trying to understand why object destruction works differently in new style classes compared to old style ones.

```
class Wrapper():
    class Inner(object):
        def __del__(self):
            print 'Inner destructor'

    innerInstance = Inner()

    def __del__(self):
        print 'Wrapper destructor'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Wrapper()
```

on exit, this will output:

```
Wrapper destructor
Inner destructor
```

however, if i use Wrapper as a new style class, only the wrapper destructor is called, and the output is:

```
Wrapper destructor
```

Could someone explain the behavior shown above ?

Comment: Duped this to the newer post, rather than the other way around, because the newer post has a) a slightly simpler illustration of the issue and b) an answer that explains *why* this happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The python [data model](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) explicitly states:

> It is not guaranteed that `__del__()` methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits.

In this case, a `Wrapper` (class and instance) object still exists when the interpreter exits, so there is no guarantee that it will be finalized.  And even though we see that the `Wrapper` **instance** is finalized, there is no gurarantee that the `Wrapper` **class** will be finalized (which is what is holding your `Inner` instance).

---

As a side note, if I run this code with Jython, `__del__` isn't called for either object (regardless of whether we're using old-style or new-style classes).  Suprisingly, It doesn't even work (with Jython) if I explicitly delete the objects (but this code does work with CPython, regardless of old-style/new-style):

```
class Wrapper():
    class Inner(object):
        def __del__(self):
            print 'Inner destructor'

    innerInstance = Inner()

    def __del__(self):
        print 'Wrapper destructor'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "foo"
    x = Wrapper()
    print "bar"
    del x
    del Wrapper
```

Comment: Does this explain why it is different for old- and new- style classes?

Comment: @DavidRobinson -- It explains that the behavior is **completely implementation dependent** and that there is no true solution to this problem.