# Python: Global Object Destruction

Tags: python

I have a global instance, which I expect to be destroyed (function `__del__` called) when the Python interpreter exits. Am I expecting too much of the Python interpreter?
My method of testing this is to put a print in the `__del__` function, run `python.exe` from a command line, and then pressing Ctrl/Break. At this point, I would expect to see the print in the command-line window. However, I do not.

Comment: OK, I have noticed a difference between terminating the Python interpreter with Ctrl/Break (__del__ not called) and with Ctrl/C (__del__ called). I therefore assume that the Ctrl/Break kills the process, whereas Ctrl/C ends it properly. What should I expect from closing the window then? (perhaps this question should be asked in a different forum though).

Comment: also of interest:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/14628486/748858

Comment: And another reason you shouldn't rely on `__del__`:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14323849/748858

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you're expecting too much. Python [doesn't make any guarantees](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__del__#object.__del__) about calling `__del__`:

> It is not guaranteed that `__del__()` methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits.

Edit:

Generally, you should avoid using `__del__`. For most cases context managers are better. For the rare case when you need to make sure that some external (i.e. allocated from C code) resource gets cleaned up when the interpreter exits you can use the [`atexit` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html).

Comment: My aim is to save the current state into a database just before the executable instance (which contains the global object in memory) is terminated. Is it conceptually wrong to perform DB operations in the destructor?

Answer (score 4):

You could add a handler for the `signal.SIGBREAK` signal.  That would let you intercept `ctrl` + `break`.  Form [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#example):

```
import signal, os

def handler(signum, frame):
    print 'Someone is trying to exit!', signum

signal.signal(signal.SIGBREAK, handler)
```

Comment: Would this handle closing the window as well?

Comment: No.  @Lqc's answer is a better fit