# Why do new style class and old style class have different behavior in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, python-internals

I found something interesting, here is a snippet of code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "A init"

    def __del__(self):
        print "A del"

class B(object):
    a = A()
```

If I run this code, I will get:

```
A init
```

But if I change `class B(object)` to `class B()`, I will get:

```
A init
A del
```

I found a note in the [__del__ doc](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__):

> It is not guaranteed that **del**() methods are called for objects
>   that still exist when the interpreter exits.

Then, I guess it's because that `B.a` is still referenced(referenced by class `B`) when the interpreter exists.

So, I added a `del B` before the interpreter exists manually, and then I found `a.__del__()` was called.

Now, I am a little confused about that. Why is `a.__del__()` called when using old style class? Why do new and old style classes have different behavior?

I found a similar question [here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/467672-__del__-not-called), but I think the answers are not clear enough.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323734/python-destructors-in-new-and-old-style-classes answer your question?

Comment: Interesting! Reproduced, and hash randomisation doesn't affect it. I suspect there may still a reference to the new-style class present when the module is torn down.

Comment: @MJeffryes: the module is cleared when the interpreter exits. So running here means running this code as a script. It is the interpreter exit that tears down the module (setting all references in it to None) and thus triggering the `A.__del__` call as the instance is cleared too.

Comment: @figs No answer for the difference between new/old style class either

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was hoping I'd deleted that before anyone noticed, I was just being dense.

Comment: @WKPlus: the issue is the same; mgilson is right though, it may be interesting there is a difference but that difference is an implementation detail.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did a test with `getrefcount` followed an answer [here](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/467672-__del__-not-called) and found that the refcount is more for new style class. I think it more clear to the answer, but I don't know how to keep on digging.

Comment: `gc.get_referrers(B.a)` shows that there is an extra reference for new-style class members `'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'B' objects>`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what will happen if the interpreter call \__del__() for all object that still exists before exiting? Will there be any obvious disadvantages?

Comment: @WKPlus: it could make shutdown significantly slower.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TL;DR: this is an [old issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue1545463) in CPython, that was finally fixed in [CPython 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#pep-442-safe-object-finalization). Objects kept live by reference cycles that are referred to by module globals are not properly finalized on interpreter exit in CPython versions prior to 3.4. New-style classes have implicit cycles in their `type` instances; old-style classes (of type `classobj`) do not have implicit reference cycles.

Even though fixed in this case, the CPython 3.4 documentation still recommends to not depend on [`__del__`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) being called on interpreter exit - consider yourself warned.

---

New style classes have reference cycles in themselves: most notably

```
>>> class A(object):
...     pass
>>> A.__mro__[0] is A
True
```

This means that they cannot be deleted instantly*, but only when the garbage collector is run. Since a reference to them is being held by the main module, they will stay in memory until the interpreter shutdown. At the end, during the module clean-up, all the module global names in the main are set to point to `None`, and whichever objects had their reference counts decreased to zero (your old-style class for example) were also deleted. However, the new-style classes, having reference cycles, would not be released/finalized by this.

The cyclic garbage collector would not be run at the interpreter exit (which is allowed by the [CPython documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__):

> It is not guaranteed that `__del__()` methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits.

---

Now, old-style classes in Python 2 do not have implicit cycles. When the CPython module cleanup/shutdown code sets the global variables to `None`, the only remaining reference to class `B` is dropped; then `B` is deleted, and the last reference to `a` is dropped, and `a` too is finalized.

---

To demonstrate the fact that the new-style classes have cycles and require a GC sweep, whereas the old-style classes do not, you can try the following program in CPython 2 (CPython 3 does not have old-style classes any more):

```
import gc
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("A init")

    def __del__(self):
        print("A del")

class B(object):
    a = A()

del B
print("About to execute gc.collect()")
gc.collect()
```

With `B` as new-style class as above, the output is

```
A init
About to execute gc.collect()
A del
```

With `B` as old-style class (`class B:`), the output is

```
A init
A del
About to execute gc.collect()
```

That is, the new-style class was deleted only after `gc.collect()` even though the last outside reference to it was dropped already; but the old-style class was deleted instantly.

---

Much of this is already [fixed](http://bugs.python.org/issue1545463) in [Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/whatsnew/3.4.html#pep-442-safe-object-finalization): thanks to [PEP 442](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/), which included the [*module shutdown procedure based on GC code*](http://bugs.python.org/issue812369). Now even on interpreter exit the module globals are finalized using the ordinary garbage collection. If you run your program under Python 3.4, the program will print

```
A init
A del
```

Whereas with Python <=3.3 it will print

```
A init
```

*(**Do note** that other implementations still might or might not execute `__del__` at this moment, regardless of the version of them being above, at, or below, 3.4)*